# Проверка сайта используя safe browsing API для Edge

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, microsoft-edge

Есть скрипт, проверяющий безопасность сайта через google safe browsing API

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=YOUR_KEY",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '  {
"client": {
  "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
  "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
},
"threatInfo": {
  "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
  "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
  "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
  "threatEntries": [
    {"url": "https://accounts-wallets.redirectme.net/webapps/57a39/websrc"},
    {"url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"}


  ]
}
  }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "postman-token: b05b8d34-85f2-49cf-0f8e-03686a71e4e9"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Подскажите есть ли что-нибудь похожее для браузера Edge?